# Carregar imagem via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tentei fazer o carregamento de imagem por `JS` porém não consegui fazer através do `onload`, segue o código que tentei:

**HTML:**

```
<img  class="razer" id="imageoption" onload="imageOption()">
```

**JS:**

```
document.onload = function imageOption() {
document.getElementById("imageoption").src = "images/hyperx-option.png"; }
```

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer, da forma que está é mais fácil por o `src="images/hyperx-option.png"` diretamente na `tag`. Pode explicar melhor o quer fazer?

Comment: Então, essa pagina vai possuir diversas marcas dependendo da opção escolhida na pagina anterior essa carrega uma marca diferente, estava tentando acertar essa parte do js com html mas não consegui fazer com que aa imagem apareça.

Comment: Você não precisa de javascript para isso, tente fazer assim: `<img  class="razer" id="imageoption" src="images/hyperx-option.png">`

Comment: Assim funciona perfeitamente, mas quando eu acessar essa mesma pagina com outra opção anterior quero que outra imagem apareça

Comment: Acho que estou começando a entender sua dúvida, como a nova página identifica qual imagem exibir? Se você está navegando de uma página para outra você consegue passar dados no caso o `src` através da `url` ou de um formulário. Qual linguagem de programação você está utilizando? Já pesquisou a respeito de `GET/POST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O evento `onload` não pode ser acessado pelo `document` ele tem que ser acessado diretamente pelo `window` ,como mostra o código abaixo.

```
window.onload = function imageOption() {
    document.getElementById("imageoption").src = "images/hyperx-option.png";
}
```

Alguns dos eventos JavaScript só são acessíveis pelo o `window` ,bem como o `onload`.

Comment: Vlw!! Funcionou

Answer (score 3):

Uma outra solução usando `Jquery`

```
<img  class="razer" id="imageoption">
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#imageoption').attr('src','images/hyperx-option.png');
   });
```

Assim que o documento for carregado, ele irá atribuir o `src` definido para a imagem.

Answer (score 0):

A função em `onload="imageOption()"` nunca vai ser chamada com `src` vazio. O `onload` é disparado justamente quando *algo* é carregado. Com o `src` vazio, esse *algo* é inexistente.

O que você pode fazer é trocar o `src` da imagem quando o DOM estiver pronto:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   document.getElementById("imageoption").src = "https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg";
});
```

```html
<img src="" class="razer" id="imageoption">
```

Answer (score -1):

## Javascript

```
function imageOption(){
   document.getElementById("imageoption").src = "images/hyperx-option.png";
}
```

## HTML

```
<body onload="imageOption()">
<img  class="razer" id="imageoption" src="" />
```

Se quiser que a imagem seja trocada dinamicamente por JavaScript use `setTimeout` dentro do final da função:

```
function imageOption(){
   document.getElementById("imageoption").src = ; // coloque a variável das condições que vai mudar a imagem
   setTimeout(function(){ imagemOption(); }, 10000); //intervalo de 10 segundos
}
```

Comment: Uma pequena observação JScript é uma variação de JavaScript ,ou seja ,essas linguagens não são a mesma coisa.

Comment: Obrigado por corrigir